# Email are going to Unresolved items, when trying to create Activity History record using `Email To Salesforce Address`

Tags: workflow, activityhistory, emailtosalesforce

I have to create the activity History record for workflow email alerts.
I tried this way

- Created another email alert with copy of same email template and appended ref:{!Lead.Id} in email template.
- email alert is associated with same workflow.
- got  `Email to Salesforce` address from admin user and mentioned at `BCC address in email alert`.
- Didn't mention any recipient as, the one who should be receipt is already being mentioned at 1st email alert.
- getting the email in unresolved item.

OR

- I tried first using single email alert while mentioning BCC address and ref:{!Lead.Id} in email template body(didn't created any new template), that was not creating even unresolved item email.

How to create correct Activity History for workflow email alert. I have read the many blogs mentioned same way, did i miss any thing in implementation. ?

Comment: Why not simply 'fix' the email template and workflow that's creating the problem for you to begin with that isn't creating the Activity History for you that's needed?

Comment: I used the exisitng workflow only. I tried first using single email alert while mentioning BCC address and `ref:{!Lead.Id}` in email template body, that was not creating even unresolved item email.

Comment: There is a user setting to send everything to unresolved items, make sure that is off.

Comment: @gorav : Yes that setting is off.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you missed something either in your your template or email messaging method. From the [Email Class (Base Email Methods)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_base.htm#apex_Messaging_Email_setSaveAsActivity), you need to use the following in your code:

> **setSaveAsActivity(saveAsActivity)**
>
> Optional. The default value is true, meaning the email is saved as an
> activity. This argument only applies if the recipient list is based on
> targetObjectId or targetObjectIds. If HTML email tracking is enabled
> for the organization, you will be able to track open rates.
>
> **Signature**
>
> public Void setSaveAsActivity(Boolean saveAsActivity)
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *saveAsActivity*
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> **Return Value**
>
> Type: Void

Comment: I am not using any code. instead workflow email alert.

Comment: Are you setting the WhatId to lead and the WhoId to the lead.Id in the template? Are you using the above in your workflow and creating an activity (closed) when sending the email?

Comment: I am using workflow on Lead object, which sends an email on record creation, for the same we want to have activity history record created under Lead.
To acheive that I used 'Email to Salesforce address' in `bcc area of email alert`.

Comment: Edit your template to include a `WhatId = lead.id` and `WhoId=lead.Id`. You can make the fields hidden if you need to. More important, you also need to change your workflow to also create a Task which you'll create as "closed". The Task will be to "send email". That's how to get this into your history. Unless you create the task to send the email, it won't appear in your history.